# Permanent case for shipping 2U servers?

Tags: rack, rackmount, server-setup

My organization ships servers (2U) to multiple sites (back and forth) and the original server boxing is becoming worn. Can someone please recommend a more permanent case?

Thanks.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can purchase an ATA-rated 4-post "flight case" for the 2U server. A nice example would be this [6U shock-mount case](http://www.racksolutions.com/transport-case.html), especially if you need to ship anything along with the server (switches, power supply, etc.). [Standard non-rackmount ATA cases](http://www.specialtycases.com/anvil-server-shipping-cases.htm) would work well, too.

[image]

Comment: Forgot yer link :-)

Comment: Thank you. This might be a little overkill - I saw vendor with a padded case that fit 2950 (Dell) very well...wish I could find it.

Comment: I'd go with the standard non-rackmount case if you're shipping the server back and forth within the same company. The shock-mount case is nice for sending a demo system to clients or to keep things organized.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you recommend a specific model from a vendor or are these all the same?

Comment: I was throwing out the general idea. I tend to like Anvil cases, but you'd need to find a dealer. http://www.anvilcase.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at cases for musical hardware; it's delicate, rack-mounted equipment that get moved around *a lot*. The hardware they tend to put in isn't as deep as the standard four-post rack-server, so YMMV.

A musician-friend of mine wasn't satisfied with what he could get, so he begun to build his own cases instead.

So: try the local music-shops; they *might* have something relevant, or, they can likely point you to someone who can custom-build it for you, if that's your thing. (Ex. sturdy replicas of your current boxes/padding?)