# Secure Standalone Server Plus Firewall Unit

Tags: shipping

We need to send a 2U server, 1U UPS and 1U firewall to a third-party.  The thing is, it needs to be a secured case (locked unit) that has proper airflow and we can have power and networking cables coming out of the back.

We've googled far and wide and have only been able to find 'hard case' units that offer some level of security but they are extremely bulky and require freight delivery.

Thank you for any insight or solutions.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking for here. You want a "soft-case" server rack?  How is it supposed to hold and secure the servers if its not rigid? What do you mean by 'hard case'? In what specific way does a standard SOHO case fail your use requirements? What do you mean by "require freight delivery" - you don't want to pay freight charges (good luck on that!) or that most cases/racks are to large to ship? What exactly *are* you trying to do? Without these details there's no way anyone can answer your question in a satisfactory manner.

Comment: We're looking for something like this: http://bit.ly/oycpXa but allows for something deeper (70" vs 19").  UPS / FedEx allow up to 150lbs, which we may be under if we could deploy using a unit shown in the URL.

Comment: Try looking at audio and sound equipment cases. They're generally tough enough so the band doesn't destroy them but not to heavy for the roadies to move. Or look for manufactures that specialize in supplying IT equipment to the military - what you're looking for sounds exactly like "field-grade" shippable rackmount equipment.

Comment: http://www.eia-rackmount-case.com/military-rackmount-cases.htm

Comment: We're already using a case-rack similar to what ewwhite [suggested](http://serverfault.com/questions/301661/permanent-case-for-shipping-2u-servers), what's different is we are deploying several of these to 3rd parties who can receive the case-rack, and (as-is/locked) fire-up the server and UPS without having to open the unit...airflow wouldn't be an issue either (another issue entirely).  Thanks for the link, depending on how successful we are using off the shelf parts, it's likely we'll contact a couple places to do some of the mods we're after.

Answer (score 2):

Before this gets closed, take a look at: [Permanent case for shipping 2U servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/301661/permanent-case-for-shipping-2u-servers)

There are also some options used in the Pro Audio industry (for housing Apple Xserves) that may work as well. A good example is the [SKB shock case](http://www.skbcases.com/music/products/proddetail.php?f=sku_rack_space_units-4-80&id=531&o=&offset=1&c=80&s=80).

Couple that with a locked server bezel or tamper-proof covers on the front rails. I'm not sure what options exist to secure the rear.

Comment: Thanks ewwhite, this is about as close as we got.  The case won't be travelling more than once every few years, but it seems what we're doing is unique (deploy a standalone (locked) datacenter to a remote site.)