# Transporting servers - need special rack/case

Tags: hardware, rack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Permanent case for shipping 2U servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/301661/permanent-case-for-shipping-2u-servers)

I am responsible for our companys server infrastructure at trade shows.
We have 2 annual shows, 1 in Las Vegas and 1 in Amsterdam, so obviously our servers do quite a bit of travelling.

Quite often, it gets home with pieces falling off, and insurance/rebuilding takes ages and cost a lot of money.

For now I have been using a wooden rack-box, with steel-reinforced sides/corners, but I am looking for something tougher.

Does anyone have experience with sending servers all around the world, without them dieing all the time?

Comment: Why do they need to travel with you? The Internet is great for accessing servers that are elsewhere ;-)

Comment: I would suggest to talk to a company that specialises in moving high-tech equipment and ask them what they use.  Ultimately though it's usually not the case that needs to be stronger but the inside padding that needs to be better  - stable yet soft enough to take the forces that happen during any transport.

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown: Well, I imagine a trade show with nothing to show then a few pictures could be a dull experience.

Comment: @SvenW Assuming that the servers are what they're selling and they're not there for some other reason, which is why I asked :-)

Comment: Why not just get some decent custom made cases? Any half decent engineering company could make something suitable.

Comment: I'm afraid we need the servers with us, Internet access is limited and crazy expensive at trade shows so we need everything to be local.

Comment: I would recommend transporting the drives with your carry-on baggage.

Comment: Are you showcasing the hardware or some application running on the hardware?

Comment: We are showing applications running on the servers, but we can not get a big enough internet connection to do it over there. And they are way too big to make it baggage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For standalone servers, I've used [standard wood/aluminum ATA-rated flight cases](http://www.specialtycases.com/anvil-server-shipping-cases.htm). That's nice for situations where the end-recipient will assemble the server and you're just looking for a nice reusable case. Shipping demo equipment is a good use-case for this.

For portable installations like trade shows, etc., I've used [shock-absorbing ATA cases](http://www.racksolutions.com/transport-case.html). These cost twice as much as standard cases, but are worth it if you need to send an entire system stack (server, networking, etc.) to a location pre-configured.

[image]

Comment: The link to wood/aluminum looks pretty much exatly like the one I use, except mine has space for 4-6 server (which is the problem, too big).
The shock-absorbing one looks like it should be able to take some more beating though, I'll look in to that :)

Comment: The case you found looks like exactly what I need, so answer accepted. Sorry for taking a while, I am new and clicked "useful" instead:)